# Eclipse keeps crashing after installation of JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, crash

Since installing JBoss eclipse keeps crashing when developing a new project. This is the information I get when it crashes. I have increased the memory available to it also but it doesn't seem to have made any difference, anyone got any ideas?? thanks.
[image: eclipse_crash_image]

Comment: I would assume a problem with memory allocation. First, it's strange having memory setting twice in the eclipse configuration (you have the switches -Xms and -Xmx two times). Second, -Xms2048m and -Xmx3548m seems really too much. I never used so much memory. Additionally, you might try to increase the perm size to 256m. Give it a try.

Comment: thank you, yea I don't understand why it is there two times, how do you increase the perm size?

Comment: In your eclipse.ini file, you have a line with "--launcher.XXMaxPermSize". Directly beneath that, you type in the max perm size. That way, you do not need a swith with "-XX:MaxPermSize" in the vmargs section.

Comment: ok perfect, I updated the "--launcher.XXMaxPermSize" and the -Xms and -Xmx in the eclipse.ini file, this solved my issue, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Ok, I would like to get upvoted for that. I will make this an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume a problem with memory allocation.

First, it's strange having memory setting twice in the eclipse configuration (you have the switches -Xms and -Xmx two times). Second, -Xms2048m and -Xmx3548m seems really too much. I never used so much memory. Additionally, you might try to increase the perm size to 256m. Give it a try.

In your eclipse.ini file, you have a line with "--launcher.XXMaxPermSize". Directly beneath that, you type in the max perm size. That way, you do not need a swith with "-XX:MaxPermSize" in the vmargs section.